# Create a new app password for Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, passwords

I am using two factor authentication on my MS account. But Outlook doesn't support this, instead I have specific app password for Outlook. I created it somewhere my MS settings, but it has now expired.

I now can't find where to create a new app password in the MS portal.

Does anyone know how to do this now?

Comment: Do you mean to encrypt a document? Which version are you using?

Comment: Made question clearer

Comment: Did you try the instructions [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/app-passwords-two-step-verification), under `I sync my Outlook.com email with the Outlook desktop app`? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: I found those instructions, but couldn't see app passwords on the page it directed me to. I found instructions that solved it for me, answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it, take a look at this page - http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/two-step-verification-faq

> 1. Sign-in to the Azure Management portal
> 2. At the top, right-click on your user name and select Additional Security Verification.
> 3. On the proofup page, at the top, select app passwords
> 4. Click Create
> 5. Enter a name for the app password and click Next
> 6. Copy the app password to the clipboard and paste it into your app.

Comment: Please update your answer to include the essential parts of the article you have linked to so if the link breaks the answer will still be valuable to future readers.

Comment: Rather than down voting, why don't you edit or suggest edits.

Comment: Although I didn't, people do down vote for may reasons. A lot of times without comments. My comment was to ask you to improve it, which you did.

Comment: @CharlieRB The "you" in my comment was not directed at CharlieRB, Your suggestions were appreciated.

Comment: Fixed your quoting to be properly bulleted text instead of code. Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).